# WPF DependencyProperty with IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to write custom WPF control with

- `IEnumerable<object> ItemSource`
- `object SelectedItem`
- `string DisplayPath`

as depencency properties.

I have problem with making this works with `object` as collection item type. It does not set my collection reference.

When I change type of collection to implicit type `IEnumerable<MyType>` it works properly.

Here's some code which I have right now (not whole, just properties initialization and usage)

```
public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable<object>) GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ItemsSource", 
    typeof (IEnumerable<object>), 
    typeof (AutoCompleteComboBox), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public object SelectedValue
{
    get { return (object) GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedValue", 
    typeof (object), 
    typeof (AutoCompleteComboBox), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public string DisplayPath
{
    get { return (string) GetValue(DisplayPathProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DisplayPathProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayPathProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DisplayPath", 
    typeof (string), 
    typeof (AutoCompleteComboBox), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
```

And I have exception in usage of ItemsSource (null reference):

```
private void atb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (atb.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        IEnumerable<object> results = ItemsSource.Where(
            delegate(object s)
            {
                var propertyInfo = s.GetType().GetProperty(DisplayPath);
                var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(s, null);
                var s1 = value as string;
                return s1.ToLower().StartsWith(atb.Text.ToLower());
            });

        if (results.Any())
        {
            slb.ItemsSource = results;
            slb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            slb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            slb.ItemsSource = null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        slb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        slb.ItemsSource = null;
    }
}
```

I'm binding ObservableCollection to this, and one more time, it all works, when I change all `object` to `MyCustomItem`

Comment: have you tried ItemsSource = new collection ? in  constructor ? I remember I had to do this

Comment: If I do this, it's also null in a place where usage if it is. It's some kind of auto-magically set to null.

Comment: in class where you have .. public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
..
in that class's constructor you have to do this

Comment: Sure... I know, but even when I'm instantiating collection in constructor, it's null in usage method. It seems that after binding it's being nulled

Comment: @Tomasz control with `ItemSource`, `SelectedItem`, and `DisplayMemberPath` sounds pretty much like `ListBox`. Why not use that?

Comment: It's an AutoCompleteBox, which uses TextBox to type and listbox for hints

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found an solution.

I have changed type of collection to `IEnumerable` (not generic), and in usage point I had to call `ItemsSource.OfType<object>()` to use Linq.